# to_csv() from pandas integer indexing is not working

Tags: pandas, export-to-csv

I am having a very strange problem with to_csv() from pandas. Integers that have comma-separated indices have behaved as float numbers thus function is chopping and rounding it. What I am trying to do is write integers with their index numbers. However, I am getting this problem.

no index, left one: `pd.DataFrame(pp).to_csv("no_index.csv", header='price', index=False)`

indexing, right one: `pd.DataFrame(pp).to_csv("no_index.csv", header='price', index_label='ID')`

As you can see in the 6th row I am losing a digit. It round numbers as well.

exp from another row:

actual -> 18139

with indexing -> 1814

[image]

Comment: How do you open your file in excel? Do you double click on your file or from excel, File > Open?

Comment: What is your decimal symbol under Control Panel > Clock and Region > Region > Additional Settings? I think Excel inherits this. I would try to change this to a dot in case it's a comma